# Read the contents of a listView, and display missing items in another listView based on the contents of a directory

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have a .NET webform that is displaying files found in a directory in a listView.  This is the code for the display:

```
private void files()
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(label2.Text);
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.doc");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

label2.Text contains the directory that houses the files.  What I need is for a second listView to display a list of documents housed in another directory to display if the file does not appear in the first list view.

The second directory contains templates where as the first directory contains completed documents.  The names are different in each directory, but they are similar.  For example a completed document displayed in the first listView may be called  DEFECT1_AA09890.doc.  It's template may be called 05DEFECT.doc.

It is easy enough to display the contents of the template directory using this code:

```
private void templateDocuments()
{
    string path = @"\\directoryname\foldername";

    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.doc");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            listView2.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But this does not compare contents and display based on the results.

Long story short, I want to display the contents of a directory in a listView, compare it to the contents of another directory, and display in a second listView what does not appear in the first.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: by my understanding you want two listview, in list1 you content from a directory and in list2 you want also want content from another directory but only those contents that were not in list1...??

Comment: Yeah it is a tricky one to explain.  ListView2 shows the contents of a directory that contains template documents.  ListView1, shows complete documents from a separate directory.  I only want to display the template documents in ListView2 that are not used in ListView1.  In other words, ListView2 will show the templates that are not filled out, ListView1 will show the ones that are.  So ListView2 reads what is in ListView1, and displays the documents that are not present based on the directory contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding file names to `listView2`, you need to check whether you already added them to `listView1`. One way of doing that is to store the files in `listView1` in a `HashSet<string>`, then checking that before adding to `listView2`. Something like this should work:

```
private void filesAndTemplates()
{
    string path = @"\\directoryname\foldername";
    HashSet<string> files = new HashSet<string>();

    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(label2.Text);
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.doc");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            files.Add(file.Name);
            listView1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }

        dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.doc");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            if (files.Contains(file.Name))
            {
                continue; // We already saw this file
            }

            listView2.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want inexact matching, you need to reduce the file name to its essence -- remove any decorations, which in your case looks to be one (or both) of

- Leading digits
- Underscore followed by whatever

The essence of `01hello_world.doc` would thus be `hello`.

`Regex` should fit the bill quite nicely -- although the exact definition of the regular expression would depend on your exact requirements.

Define the `Regex` and a transformation method somewhere suitable:

```
private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(
    @"[0-9]*(?<core>[^_]+)(_{1}.*)?", RegexOptions.Compiled);

private static string Transform(string fileName)
{
    int extension = fileName.LastIndexOf('.');
    if (extension >= 0)
    {
        fileName = fileName.Substring(0, extension);
    }

    Match match = regex.Match(fileName);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        return match.Groups["core"].Value;
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

Then modify the original method to transform the filename before adding files to the `HashSet` and before checking for their presence:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(label2.Text);
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.doc");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    files.Add(Transform(file.Name)); // Here!
    listView1.Items.Add(file.Name);
}

dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.doc");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    if (files.Contains(Transform(file.Name))) // Here!
    {
        continue;
    }

    listView2.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

Note the two calls to `Transform`.

Comment: Thanks Petter, but is there a way I can set it to not display the file if the list 1 has a file LIKE it?  for example, list one has a file called PRE-INSPECT_A03345.doc, therefore I don't want list 2 to display 01PRE-INSPECT.doc.

Comment: Thank you that runs very nicely.